# A reference for AT&T syntax assembly floating point arithmetic

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

I've been trying for the past week to find a decent resource on floating point arithmetic for x86 assembly using AT&T syntax. Ideally, a list of the opcodes, what they do, and where the floats are stored. I am familiar with IEEE 754 representation. I am not familiar with the floating point stack, and any assembly referring to floating point arithmetic.

It's strange how difficult this is to find.

EDIT: I've been looking at gcc -S output for the past month learning the assembly. That's how I figured out everything except floating point arithmetic. Even after going through dozens of small programs compiled without optimizations, I still can't figure out much about the floating point opcodes and the stack. I've only found trivial examples online.

Comment: Re edit: So, follow the suggestion to read `libm`, and read the Intel manuals. I'm sorry, you have no alternative. There are _no_ decent AT&T-syntax-based resources, because _nobody_ serious about x86 assembly programming uses it.

Comment: Okay, so I was a little too harsh about saying that nobody serious uses AT&T syntax. Anyway, if you Google for "devpro-libm", you can download the `libm` code used in OpenSolaris. This may be a more lightweight download than `glibc`. Then, look in the `usr/src/libm/src/i386/common` directory---it's a goldmine of hardcore floating-point assembly, all written in AT&T syntax.

Comment: I was actually just about to download that. Thanks :) I also dislike the AT&T syntax and it has some serious inconsistencies--but I have to use what I have to use. Despite being Intel syntax, [this](http://www.programmers-corner.com/tutorial/31) is a concise guide similar to what I was looking for. The changes to accommodate AT&T syntax are easy.

Comment: +1 Wow, that's a pretty comprehensive guide, at least at a brief glance (I know x86 FP, so didn't feel the need to read through it in detail ;-)). Yep, hopefully between that and the `libm` code, you'll be all sorted. The latter is actually very well-commented, it's not just a big bunch of magic spells. :-P

Comment: Yep, I should be set now. Well, after a week of making sure my compiler spits out somewhat decent code that works. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. Start with Intel syntax first, because most x86 assembly coders use it. [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) are a great resource for learning about how the x86 handles floating-point stuff.

After you learn x86 assembly in general, AT&T syntax isn't so hard to learn. The main things to note are:

- registers are prefixed by `%`; numeric constants are prefixed by `$`
- register order is swapped for most two-operand instructions (i.e., source first, target last)
- instruction names specify the size; so instead of `mov dword ptr [ebx], 1337`, you'd say `movl $1337, (%ebx)`.

Comment: I can't use intel syntax. This is for a compiler project and we're using AT&T syntax so it works with gcc.

Comment: @Kizaru: I know you can't _use_ it for your project. But you should _learn_ with it first. Use nasm as your assembler, initially. Then, once you get the hang of x86 assembly programming, _then_ use AT&T syntax. Have your project be able to output to both formats, initially targeting nasm, if you want.

Comment: I have the compiler fully set for everything except floats at the moment. It's the one thing holding me back. This is a project for a course.

Comment: @Kizaru: Okay. Other suggestions for you, then: 1. Look at the `libm` source code; much of it is written in x86 assembly, and yes, in AT&T syntax. (On GNU/Linux, this comes as part of `glibc`.) 2. Compile some floating-point code in GCC, and look at its assembly output.

Comment: Suggestion: Write some floating point code in C and compile it with gcc -S.  This will quickly show you what you need to know to deal with FP from AT&T syntax.  In general, flip the operands of any two-instruction Intel-syntax instruction; there are a few exceptions, but they're very few and far between.